# 'tuple' object has no attribute '_committed' error while updating image objects?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Here I am trying to update each product image of a particular product. But it is not working properly. Here only the image of first object is updating.

There is a template where we can update product and product images at once. `ProductImage` has a `ManyToOne` relation with `Product` Model so in the template there can be multiple images objects of a single product.

Updating product model works fine but while updating ProductImage Objects it is not working.

Instead of zipping is there any other way to update multiple image objects at once ?

**EDIT:** If I unzip the images list then updating doesn't works properly. For example if I change the image of one object then the another object images changes.
***BUT*** when I change all the image objects images then the update works fine. It doesn't work properly when I change only some of the objects.

When I Zip then images list then this is the error traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 73, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "dashboard\product\views\views.py", line 293, in post
    p.save()
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 751, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 789, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 867, in _save_table
    for f in non_pks]
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 867, in <listcomp>
    for f in non_pks]
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 303, in pre_save
    if file and not file._committed:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

models

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='imgs',blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

template

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{product_form}}
    <th>Current Image</th>
    <th>Change</th>
    {% for image in p_images %}
    <tr><td>{{image.pk}}</td>
    <td><img src="{{image.image.url}}" width="50" height="50"></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="image"></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
   <input type="submit">
```

views

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
    product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=product)
    images = zip(request.FILES.getlist('image')) 
    p_images = ProductImage.objects.filter(product=product).order_by('pk')
    if product_form.is_valid():
        product_form.save()             
        
       # updating product images 
        for p, img in zip(p_images, images):  # error is here
           p.image = img
           p.save()

           # Tried this way too:

       for img in images:
           ProductImage.objects.filter(product=product).update(image=img)
```

Comment: can you add a complete code snippet that helps to ***reproduce the situation***? As of now, your view code snippet isn't a complete one

Comment: Apart from that, the `ProductImage` have only a ***single*** image field, How could someone store multiple images into that *single* field? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu  sorry for the bad title. I was meant to update multiple product image objects at pnce?

Comment: Are you familiar with PDB (python debugger, as mentioned here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)? If not, try to. It's often a great way to plow through your code to see why things aren't working as intended. It's also quite simple and might just explain why your solution is not working as intended.

Comment: @Ludo21South the problem is in the forloop. with zipping the images list and queryset

Comment: @D_P What's the error?

Comment: Please add errors stacktrace

Comment: @aaron error is `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_committed'` when I update image. Added the full traceback in the question

Comment: Consider moving this business logic to ProductForm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change `input` `name` to be able to identify which `ProductImage` was updated.

```html
<!-- <td><input type="file" name="image"></td> -->
     <td><input type="file" name="image-{{image.pk}}"></td>
```

Next, iterate the `input_name` in `request.FILES` and get the `ProductImage` PK.
Then, lookup the `ProductImage` `p`, update the `image` field and `save` the model.

```py
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
    product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=product)
    if product_form.is_valid():
        product_form.save()

        # Updating product images
        if request.FILES:
            p_images = ProductImage.objects.filter(product=product).order_by('pk')
            p_images_lookup = {p_image.pk: p_image for p_image in p_images}
            for input_name in request.FILES:
                p = p_images_lookup[int(input_name[len('image-'):])]
                p.image = request.FILES[input_name]
                p.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

You’re unnecessarily zipping `request.FILES.getlist(“images”)` leading to an array containing tuples, each containing an image object.

## Solution

Change

`images = zip(request.FILES.getlist('image'))`

To

`images = request.FILES.getlist('image')`

## Reference

Django request.FILES.getlist usage: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

Comment: I tried this way and uploading doesn't work properly. For example if I change the image of one  object then the another objects image changes.

Comment: But if i change all the images list then update works but it doesn't work properly if I don't change the  complete list of images

Comment: @D_P Just check whether images is empty before assigning.